# Can you prepare a Pull Request and fix the conflict without merging yet?

Tags: git, bitbucket

**Edit for clarification:** I want to have the commit fixing the conflict not on the `issue-123` branch nor on the `dev` branch. But kind of integrated into the PR.

Problem: We want to merge `issue-123` into `dev`.
After creating a PR (Pull Request) we see it has a conflict.

IMPORTANT: Because `dev` has code not related to `issue-123` we can NOT merge `dev` into `issue-123`, nor merge `issue-123` into `dev` yet.

So we want to prepare the PR, so it has no more conflicts and anyone can just merge the PR whenever they want to. While the `issue-123` branch would still compile on it's own.

Comment: Rebase issue-123 onto dev?

Comment: Rebase can still give merge conflict.

Comment: Well you have to resolve that conflict _somewhere_ to be able to merge the PR cleanly.

Comment: Yeah thought so, thought there might have been an advanced way to commit to the PR or something like that. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

You can do on your terminal

```
git checkout dev

git reset --hard origin/dev

git checkout issue-123

git rebase dev
```

If you have conflicts, you can solve them directly into the code and than go on with the rebase.
At the end of the rebase:

```
git push origin issue-123 --force
```

End then you won't have any conflict on your PR

Comment: I think you can skip the two first steps and do `git rebase origin/dev` directly. I usually use the `-i` / `--interactive` flag, which gives more control and helps you understand what the rebase does. `git rebase -i origin/dev`

Comment: You should virtually always `--force-with-lease`, which checks that the remote hasn't changed in the meantime.